# Grouping numbers based on closest sum to a specific value with Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
 v |   c   
---+-------
 Z |   217
 J |   620
 U |  1891
 F |  3751
 A |  5673
 Y |  5859
 O |  7347
 K |  9827
 I | 11842
 R | 11997
 H | 14818
 M | 18321
 G | 18445
 E | 19220
 D | 22444
 W | 22692
 T | 24428
 P | 26257
 N | 35247
 L | 41416
 C | 42594
 B | 43586
 S | 59613
```

How can I group those values in a way that every single group has the closest possible value to 60000?

For example (not probably the best fit):

```
Z + J + U + F + A + Y + O + K + I + R -- 59024
S -- 59613
B + H -- 58404
etc.
```

Comment: How big is your table? Can elements appear in more than one set?

Comment: They are usually a bunch of small tables like that, mostly generated a runtime, and not, they cannot appear in more than one set

Comment: And you absolutely need to do this inside PostgreSQL and not in some application? (seems complicated to me in an RDBMS)

Comment: Without extra rules I am not even sure this can be computed in deterministic way. What if you have A=59999, B=60001, C=0, D=1, E=59998? Is the expected result A+D,B+C,E or A,B+C,D+E, (same global delta of 3 in both cases) etc.

Comment: The sum cannot be more than 60000

Comment: It looks like the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem which is NP-complete. Are you looking for a brute-force approach in SQL? It would be practically usable only with very small sets.

Comment: @DanielVérité interesting suggestion thank you. Yes brute-force on small datasets can be ok for my case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit of research reveals that this question is known as the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)  in computer science.

On stackoverflow, Lukas Eder provides an [Oracle solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720029/compare-a-number-with-sum-of-subset-of-numbers) to a similar question, and a [longer analysis](http://blog.jooq.org/2015/10/26/how-to-find-the-closest-subset-sum-with-sql/) on jooq's blog.

Here's a postgres version derived from his work:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(v text, c int);

-- populate table
INSERT INTO tab(v,c) VALUES('Z', 217);
etc...

-- show 10 better results

WITH RECURSIVE sums (subset_sum, max_v, a) AS (
        SELECT
            c,v,array[v] as a
        FROM
            tab

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            c + subset_sum,
            v,
            array_append(a, v)
        FROM
            sums
        JOIN
            tab
        ON sums.max_v < tab.v
    )
SELECT subset_sum, a FROM sums WHERE subset_sum <= 60000
ORDER BY 60000-subset_sum
LIMIT 10;
```

The result with the sample data is:

```
 subset_sum |      a      
------------+-------------
      59985 | {A,K,N,O,U}
      59985 | {I,K,R,T,U}
      59985 | {A,G,J,N}
      59985 | {A,F,G,P,Y}
      59985 | {C,K,O,Z}
      59985 | {A,C,F,J,O}
      59985 | {F,H,L}
      59985 | {D,E,M}
      59985 | {A,C,K,U}
      59985 | {E,J,K,M,R}
(10 rows)
```

Note that the execution time will grow exponentially with the row count in the base table.

Comment: Really great solution! love it!